# Will an item submitted to the main `DispatchQueue` ever interrupt currently executing code on the main thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading

The below code is used to execute a long running calculation on a background thread:

```
enum CalculationInterface {

    private static var latestKey: AnyObject?   // Used to cancel previous calculations when a new one is initiated.

    static func output(from input: Input, return: @escaping (Output?) -> ()) {
        self.latestKey = EmptyObject()
        let key = self.latestKey!   // Made to enable capturing `self.latestKey's` value.  

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            do {
                let output = try calculateOutput(from: input, shouldContinue: { key === self.latestKey })   // Function cancels by throwing an error.
                DispatchQueue.main.async { if (key === self.latestKey) { `return`(output) } }
            } catch {}
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called from the main thread like so:

```
/// Initiates calculation of the output and sets it to the result when finished.
private func recalculateOutput() {
    self.output = .calculating    // Triggers calculation in-progress animation for user.
    CalculationInterface.output(from: input) { self.output = $0 }   // Ends animation once set and displays calculated output to user.
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible for the closure that's pushed to `DispatchQueue.main` to execute while the main thread is running my code. Or in other words execute after `self.output = .calculating` but before `self.latestKey` is re-set to the new object. If it could, then the stale calculation output could be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it's possible for the closure that's pushed to `DispatchQueue.main` to execute while the main thread is running my code

No, it isn't possible. The main queue is a serial queue. If code is running on the main queue, no "other" main queue code can run. Your `DispatchQueue.main.async` effectively means: "Wait until all code running on the main queue comes naturally to an end, and *then* run this on the main queue."

On the other hand, `DispatchQueue.global()` is *not* a serial queue. Thus it is theoretically possible for two calls to `calculateOutput` to overlap. That isn't something you want to have happen; you want to be sure that any executing instance of `calculateOutput` finishes (and we proceed to grapple with the `latestKey`) before another one can start. In other words, you want to ensure that the sequence

- set `latestKey` on the main thread
- perform `calculateOutput` in the background
- look at `latestKey` on the main thread

happens coherently. The way to ensure that is to set aside a DispatchQueue that you create with `DispatchQueue(label:)`, that you will always use for running `calculateOutput`. That queue will be a serial queue by default.

Comment: I noticed the overlap. I would prefer it to not happen, but it appears to me my code is eventually consistent, in that simultaneous calculations may occur, but only the latest one will ever get to the point of executing `return`. If that's the case, I'm okay with foregoing creating a new queue; even though it's starting to make me feel a little lazy.